# how to pass data from cell to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pushviewcontroller

[@TusharMordiya Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95CBL.png) 
I have created a tableView inside a CollectionView.The contents of the view are UIImage and a UILabel.I want to design the cell in which when I click on a cell the image and label must go to another ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class ExploreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

   @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

   var namearr = ["images-1", "images-2", "images-3", "images-4", "images-5"]

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
    
      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self

   }
   override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 10
   }



   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
      return cell
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return CGSize(width: 132, height: 134)
   }


   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
      let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "DetailViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
    
      vc?.name = namearr[indexPath.row]
      vc?.img.image = UIImage(named: namearr[indexPath.row])
      //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
      // showing error in here and while declaring object of viewcontroller
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess you might want to unwrap the `vc`. BUT showing full error message you have might help. We can help you understand it. I guessed the error, but it could be something else...

Comment: I read more carefully your code (I wouldn't have needed if you'd show the error message). But you have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell, so here `self` is a `UITableViewCell`, not a `UIViewController`. You need to tell back the `UIViewController` with a `closure`, or `delegate` system to push the new viewcontroller with the corresponding data.

Comment: I would question why you have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell? Are you trying to create horizontal scrolling rows in the table view? If that's the case I would suggest not using UITableView at all and looking at the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Comment: @Larme i have error at didSelectItemAt indexPath and in instantiating storyboard

Comment: What is the real error message? It's important to show the **real message**, not a "pseudo one".

Comment: Thread 1: "Could not find a storyboard named 'DetailViewController' in bundle NSBundle      DetailViewController is used to display the UIImage and UILabel in another ViewController

Comment: Is your detail view controller in a different storyboard.  It wouldn't seem so.  And if it is it isn't called DetailViewController.storyboard

Comment: @Paulw11 no its just another viewcontroller in same storyboard

Comment: So, that is the cause of your exception message, but as others have said this code doesn't really belong in your cell. You need it in your view controller where you can trivially access he current storyboard.

Comment: You have an runtime error. It's different, I thought you had a compiler error (which you should have if you uncomment the `self.present()` line)... I you wouldn't have specificied the real message, I would have NEVER guessed that was the issue. Everything was pointing to the compiler error. Did you set the identifier name for `DetailViewController`?

Comment: if i uncomment the line self.navigationcontroller.......     it will show an error like "Value of type 'ExploreTableViewCell' has no member 'navigationController' "

Comment: how to perfom delegate menthod in here can anyone answer that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

1. Add function for get top most view controller

   ```
   extension UIApplication {

        class func topViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                                .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
                                .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                                .first?.windows
                                .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
                return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
            }
            if let tab = viewController as? UITabBarController {
                if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                    return topViewController(selected)
                }
            }
            if let presented = viewController?.presentedViewController {
                return topViewController(presented)
            }
            return viewController
        }
    }
   ```
2. Use this code in your **didSelectItemAt** method

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       if let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {

         vc.name = namearr[indexPath.row]
         print("You tapped the cell\(indexPath) with car name \(namearr[indexPath.row]) ")
         UIApplication.topViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your Detail Screen

   ```
   class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!

      var name = ""


      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          lbl.text = name
          img.image = UIImage(named: name)

      }
   }
   ```

Comment: can u say what the code means

Comment: @JESTINSAJI You can not use self in your collectionviewcell so the method  topViewController returns viewcontroller which are on top in navigation stack. by using that you can navigate to viewcontroller. in your code your mistake is you write viewcontroller identifier when create storyboard object. you should write storyboard name instead of viewcontroller identifier

Comment: it worked but   "vc.img.image = UIImage(named: namearr[indexPath.row])"
for this line im getting the error Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @JESTINSAJI I've updated my answer. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: @TusharMordiya its not navigating to the detailViewController when i click the cell(image). It prints that line in console only. I commented the line and checked, then nothing is happening

Comment: @JESTINSAJI Please check now. I've update my answer.

Comment: @TusharMordiya  Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'topViewController' now showing this error

Comment: @JESTINSAJI  please add extension of UIApplication which i have added in my answer. check carefully my answer and do replace or change in your code. before i have added method for topMostViewController and now i have added extension.

Comment: @TusharMordiya plz check the image i have added

Comment: @JESTINSAJI  you need to write extension out of class. please cut that extension code and add outside of class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
```

change storyBoard name to Main